# Set elements of a java array from another class or file

Tags: java, game-engine

I'm making a game right now and I'm trying to setup a CreatePlayer method.

In the main class, I take the Player class as an object to get its variables, methods ect.

```java
package com.deud07.main;

import com.deud07.player.Player;

public class Main {
    
    public static Player player = new Player("Bob", 86, null);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(player.Position);
    }
}
```

The 3rd parameter of Player is the Position, which is an array.
The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure how to set each element of the array without writing:

```java
position[0] = 1f;
position[1] = -6f;
position[2] = 0f;
```

The code for Player:

```java
package com.deud07.player;

public class Player {
    public static String Name;
    public static int ID;
    
    public static float x;
    public static float y;
    public static float z;
    public static float[] Position = {x, y, z};
    
    public Player(String name, int id, float[] pos) {
        Player.Name = name;
        Player.ID = id;
        Player.Position = pos;
    }
    
    public void createPlayer(String name, int id, float[] pos) {
        Player player = new Player(name, id, pos);
        
        player.Name = name;
        player.ID = id;
        player.Position = pos;
    }
}
```

Any solutions? And while you're at it, anything I can do to fix up my code?

Comment: Your fields of the `Player` class should most likely not be `static`. Do you know that the keyword `static` means? Why do you want all the fields to be `static`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're asking for a shorthand method. You might also find them as "one liners". The way to initiate an array in one line without a variable is as follows:

```java
Player player = new Player("Bob", 86, new float[]{1f, -6f, 0f});
```

As for "fixing your code", it goes outside of the actual question you've posted. Two things I can say are

1. Java conventions state that variables must be camel case. So your `Player` class' attributes should be `name`, `id` and `position`.
2. Your method `createPlayer()` does exactly the same the constructor does, thus it is not necessary. To create a new `Player`, just use... well, `new Player()`.

Also, `x`, `y` and `z` are kind of useless. If you need x for example, just use `position[0]` instead.